# Compare text file and pandas dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, txt

I have a pandas dataframe with 4 columns.

dataframe 1:

```
file    test1   test2   test3   test4
50001   6789999 1789999 89999   69999
50002   76  999 6999    6789
50003   1790001 67999   67999   9789999
```

and a test.txt file with same four columns. The text file has no headers and column values will be identified based on certain conditions.

```
50001   6789999 1789999 89999   69999
50002   5790000 999 6999    6789
50003   1790001 67999   67999   9789999
```

I want to compare both files with the common element  filename and write the output in two different files (matched and unmatched rows ).
matched - if all columns are matched.
unmatched - even if one column is not matched.

Expected output:

Matched file.txt:

```
50001   6789999 1789999 89999   69999
50003   1790001 67999   67999   9789999
```

Unmatched file.txt:

```
50002   76  999 6999    6789
```

Any pointers would be welcome

Comment: Since you have no headers, do you consider the headers/order to be identical?

Comment: yes, the order will be identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force `df1`'s columns on `df2` with [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html), then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` and split the rows based on the match:

```
tmp = df1.merge(df2.set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1),
                how='left', indicator=True)

match = tmp.pop('_merge').eq('both')

tmp[match].to_csv('matched.txt', index=False)
tmp[~match].to_csv('unmatched.txt', index=False)
```

Output:

```
# matched.txt
file,test1,test2,test3,test4
50001,6789999,1789999,89999,69999
50003,1790001,67999,67999,9789999

# unmatched.txt
file,test1,test2,test3,test4
50002,76,999,6999,6789
```